# NSSegmentedControl within tool bar like Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol

I would like to implement a NSSegmentedControl like those in the XCode 4 toolbar (View or Editor). I don't manage to adjust an image within it and I can not set up the frame using Interface Builder. What is the best strategy to follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the cells of Xcode's segmented controls look like stock AppKit segments.
To achieve that appearance, choose *Capsule* for the **Style** setting and *Select Any* for **Mode** (to get multiple selection).

The emboss effect for the images is automatically applied to all black images whose name ends with "Template". In the attached screenshot I used some stock template images (e.g. `NSFlowViewTemplate`) from Interface Builder.

[image: Xcode style segmented control]

**Update**
Regarding frame size: NSSegmentedControls have a fixed height (3 control size settings: Regular, Small & Mini) and variable widths (per segment).

Comment: Thanks for the precision. I already setted up those settings. The problem is that I do not manage to adjust the height with Interface Builder. Do you know how I can set up the height of the whole control segment ?

Comment: Height is fixed - You can only influence it via the controls size setting. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for yours precisions :) Maybe two more questions :

Comment: First : are image from Xcode segmented control availbles ? Second : I did not found in the documentation the information about the emboss effect that applies automatically with black images whose name ends with "Template". Could you give me some references ?

Comment: No - The Xcode images seem to be custom. The template info docs can be found in the NSImage class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/View_Type_Template_Images